# How to write regex in elasticsearch "URI Search" style

Tags: regex, elasticsearch

I want to query Elasticsearch using the "URI Search" format (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-uri-request.html#search-uri-request) with a regex but cannot find out how to deal with regex special characters symbols like \s and the simple space.

Let's say I have the term [ apple computer ] stored in my index (keyword analyzer used).
the term will be found with :

- `curl -XGET  http://es:9200/myindex/mytype/_search?q=name:/.*comp.*/&pretty`
- `curl -XGET  http://es:9200/myindex/mytype/_search?q=name:/.*appl.*/&pretty`
- `curl -XGET  http://es:9200/myindex/mytype/_search?q=name:/.*pple.*/&pretty`

but what syntax should I use (in curl, or with another tool) to query using these regex :

```
 /.*pple\s+compu.*/
 /.*le +compu.*/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've found the asnwer to my question:
First with my index setting being like this, I need to use name.keyword for a full text search

```
{
  "myindex" : {
    "aliases" : { },
    "mappings" : {
      "mytype" : {
        "properties" : {
          "name" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "fields" : {
              "keyword" : {
                "type" : "keyword",
                "ignore_above" : 256
              }
            }
          }
...
```

Then, doing a query using the "URI Search" format I have to use the tipycal conversion
a space should be written as +
+ should be written as %2b
anyother special characters in a url should be written with its %ASCII equivalent
so it turns out my regular expression `/.*le +compu.*/` must be queried like that :
`curl -XGET  "http://es:9200/myindex/mytype/_search?q=name.keyword:/.*pple+%2bcomp.*/&pretty"`
Finally, I can't see in the [regexp](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-regexp-query.html) doc or lucene any mention of the `\s` symbol as a wildcard for space, but not a big deal as it can be rewritten using regexp sub-patterns.